# Dockerfile, write output from bash script to ENV

Tags: docker

Im using the library [wkhtmltopdf](https://github.com/wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf) inside my container. In order to be able to use the library, I need to be able to get the path to the binary. This path I can get, by writing:

```
which wkhtmltopdf
```

The path is obviously different depending on the environment, thus I need to be able to specify the path as an environment variable.

In my dockerfile, it for some reason doesn't seem straight forward to achieve this because commands are run inside individual "containers" (??).

I have tried the following:

```
RUN apt-get update && \
      apt-get -y install sudo
RUN sudo apt-get -y install wkhtmltopdf
ENV wkhtmltopdf=$(which wkhtmltopdf)
```

But this doesn't work.. I was wondering if its possible to run bash inline e.g. `echo which wkhtmltopdf` and print it to the env?

Comment: Just use RUN export wkhtmltopdf=$(which wkhtmltopdf)

Comment: "The path is obviously different depending on the environment" -- except it's not, because you're running in a container image so you're always running in the same environment.

Comment: Sometimes I run the solution locally, which doesn't require me to pack it in a container - And there the path is different, depending on whether i run it on windows or osx

Comment: The Debian package probably installs the binary into `/usr/bin`, or somewhere else on the normal search path.  Do you actually need the true path to it, or is just setting `ENV wkhtmltopdf=wkhtmltopdf` enough?

Comment: I guess I could do without getting the true path. But for some reason I got stubborn, and now I want to know :-)